# Why on IE those div's are not placed under each other?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've got this piece of HTML:

```
<div class="lightbox" id="filename1.jpg">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="close-div"><a class="close" href="#">X</a></div>
        <div class="photo-content">
            <img src="../photos/filename1.jpg">
            <div class="desc">Some description.....</div>
        </div>
        <div class="prev-next-div">
            <a class="prev" href="#filename10.jpg">Previous</a>
            <a class="next" href="#filename2.jpg">Next</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this piece of CSS:

```
.lightbox {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    color: #333333;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
}

.lightbox:target {
    opacity: 1;
    outline: none;
    top: 0;
}

.lightbox .box {
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: min-content;
    display: -ms-inline-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;
    /*min-width:500px;*/
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding:10px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1400px rgba(40,33,101,0.67);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1400px rgba(40,33,101,0.67);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1400px rgba(40,33,101,0.67);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.lightbox .box > p:nth-child(2) 
{
    -ms-grid-row:2;
    display:inline-block;
}

.lightbox .title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.lightbox .photo-content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5% auto 0;
}


.lightbox .close {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color:#858585;
}

.clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.lightbox .photo-content .desc {
   z-index:99;
   bottom:0;
   position:absolute;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
   margin:0 0 8px 0;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

   color:#fff;
   font-size:17px;
   opacity:0;
   transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.5s;    
}   

.lightbox .photo-content:hover .desc   {
   opacity:1;
}

.lightbox .next,
.lightbox .prev,
.lightbox .close {
   display:block;
   text-decoration:none;
   font-size:22px;
   color:#858585;
}

.prev {
   float:left;
}

.next,
.close {
   float:right;
   text-align: right;
}

.close-div {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
.prev-next-div {
    clear: both;
    /*float: left;*/
    position: relative;
    /*margin: 99% 0 0 0;*/
}

.clear {
   display:block;
   clear:both;
}
```

and on all browsers it looks like this:
[image: Mozilla and other browsers preview]

but on IE it looks like this:
[image: IE preview]

I'm talking about those Previous and Next buttons. On IE they are on the top of the box but they should be on the bottom.

I'm trying to get this done the whole day.

Any help will appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `clear: both` from `.prev-next-div {}`

Comment: @Adam Nothing has changed

Comment: @Adam I'm using IE11

Comment: @kuba12 I found your problem. You are using IE :)

Comment: @Jeff.Clark hahh the problem is that not only me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `clear: both;` to `.photo-content`'s properties.

Comment: Your problem is IE is not calculating the height of the photo container. You can assign a fixed height or coerce it with `float: left;`, but you'll lose the auto left/right margin in that case.

Comment: After adding height property and float:left; to .photo-content anything has changed ;/